How can I determine if authorization header exists on global axios instance?
I have a global axios instance used to make requests from Microsoft Graph Api. The Authorization header needs to be set with an access token, which I am doing in a useEffect in a root route like so
import { graphAxios } from '../../services/azureServices'

const { data: token, isLoading } = trpc.auth.getSessionToken.useQuery()
useEffect(() => {
   if(token){
          graphAxios.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
            config.headers.Authorization = token.access_token
            return config
          })
    }

},[token])

how can be assured in any given place in my app that the authorization header is set before making any requests? I tried setting global state but as is's using a callback cannot be assured that the auth header was truly set

Yes, If you are using a request interceptor that ensures every time before the request reaches the server, request headers have that authorization header.
In other end you can do
export default function RequestInterceptor({
  children,
}: RequestInterceptorProps) {
  const { data: token, isLoading } = trpc.auth.getSessionToken.useQuery()


  graphAxios.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
            config.headers.Authorization = token.access_token
            return config
  })  

  return <>{children}</>;
}

And wrap your main layout with this component.

my issue is that children can be returned before the header is actually set, as it is using a callback
